# How to make that box fixed?

Tags: html, css

Im new to HTML/CSS and Im playing around a little bit with float.
What I want to do is making the left green box fixed when its getting smaller than 150 pixels (NOT the screen, what I mean is the box itself. When you play around then you see every width is moving relative with % and I want the green box moving like it does right now but when that box becomes smaller than 150px it should stop from getting smaller in width). I was trying to achieve that by adding min-width: 150px but this just kills the layout when its getting smaller so that the three boxes of the DIV are not in one line anymore.

(Please ignore those many IDs, its just for practicing)

```css
#a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #ea0000;
    }

    #b {
    width: 15%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #0aa699;
    float:left;
    }

    #c1 {
    width: calc(85% / 2);
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #00ACEE;
    float:right;
    }

    #c2 {
    width: calc(85% / 2);
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ac2aa1;
    float:right;
    }

    #d {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #ff8300;
    }

    .clear:before, .clear:after {    
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    }
```

```html
        <header>
            <div id="a">
            </div>
        </header>


        <div class="clear">

            <section>
                <div id="b"></div>
            </section>

            <aside>
                <div id="c1"></div>
                <div id="c2"></div>
            </aside>

        </div>


        <footer>
            <div id="d"></div>
        </footer>
```

Comment: whilst you're learning html and css checkout bootstrap, it helps with a lot of relative sizing.

Comment: thanks Rhys, thats what I want to do after I've learned all the basics.

Comment: johnny, please if you want to become what is considered a good front end developer, stay away from bootstrap and continue with what you're doing now.

Comment: Agreed with @Aaron, you use bootstrap, if you want to, **after** you learn how to do this kind of stuff and make your own desicions instead of learning a framework only and become a developer that can't think for himself.

Comment: @RhysBradbury not saying you're wrong, just saying its better to learn.

Comment: Always good to learn fundamental principles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue here:

https://jsfiddle.net/vkfd2t6b/1/

What I've done is set a min-width of 150px to `#b`. Then the `aside` wrapper is where I've set the width of `width: calc(100% - 150px);`. I've then floated `aside` right. The two elements inside `aside` are then just set to 50%.

```
#b { 
   min-width: 150px; 
}        
aside {
   width: calc(100% - 150px);
   float: right;
}
#c1, #c2 {
   width: 50%;
}
```

Additionally I've added a media query so that when the div is greater than 150px it switches the `aside` width calculation to 15% instead of 150px

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px){
   aside {
      width: calc(100% - 15%);
   }
}
```

Comment: sorry for missunderstanding, what I mean is: If you play around with the code right now, all the boxes in the DIV are moving relative with %, but now when the green box becomes smaller than 150px it should stop getting smaller and stay at 150px. I dont mean the content connected to the viewport

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't quite understand, I'll do a new answer for you!

Comment: thanks for effort matt. this works great but when the green box becomes bigger, then it also kills the layout by pushing the purple and blue box in a new line. I think thats because aside is fix at 100%-150px

Comment: Edited the answer again! Works now :)

Comment: thanks. I added #b {width: 15%;} to your media query then it worked ;)